# "fake Twitter accounts believed to be linked"

Tags: grammar

*Just yesterday it emerged that hundreds of **fake Twitter accounts believed to be linked** to the Kremlin had been used to influence British politics*.

Source: https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2017/nov/15/russia-meddle-western-politics-putin-superpower

I suppose that the above sentence is grammatically correct. But the passage in bold in my non-native speaker opinion suggests that Twitter accounts have the capability to believe. Is this standard form? I would write: *Just yesterday it emerged that it is believed that hundreds of fake Twitter accounts to be linked to the Kremlin had been used to influence British politics.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly standard English.

"Believed" is a *passive* past participle, so when it introduces a clause modifying "accounts", it is not the accounts doing the believing, but an (unspecified) agent.

Having said that, there is some [raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_(linguistics)) going on, because what these unspecified people believe is not "the accounts" but "that the accounts are linked".

Comment: +1 The participle clause is understood by transformational grammar to be a relative clause reduced by 'Whiz deletion': "fake Twitter accounts *which are* believed to be linked..."